# Question on Uniswap v3 SDK

Tags: solidity, dapps, hardhat, uniswap

I am about to create a dapp with UniswapV3 SDK. I have a very basic doubt, can I deploy that project using hardhat? I am worrying as i creating the dapp using SDK so i might not be able to deploy the dapp because SDK uses type script.

Answer (score 1):

The UniswapV3 SDK if for interacting with frontend/off chain code. The SDK basically helps you interact and do things with uniswap V3 from typescript or other centralized services.

I don't know exactly what you mean by a DAPP in this case, but if your dapp uses smart contracts that plug into uniswap V3, you should be looking at https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core, and https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery to figure out how your smart contracts need to plug in and talk to the uniswap contracts instead.

The uniswapV3 SDK might still be useful for when you are building out a front end, or say an arbitrage bot, but if you want to have contract interactions with uniswap V3, you need to be looking at their contracts. Specifically, take a look at the interface files in solidity (IContractName.sol), to figure out what functions you can call from your smart contract.